# How to reveal TikZ plot with \printanswers in exam class

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, graphs, exam, answers

In the [exam class](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf), you can reveal solutions by uncommenting the command `\printanswers`. This allows the author to keep both question and solution in the same document, without needing to manually comment and uncomment each individual solution.

Using `\begin{solution}...\end{solution}` I can follow up printing a blank axis alongside with a *separate* graph containing the solution plot, but this has the side-effect of using a lot of space, paper, and ink.

When `\printanswers` is issued, in a similar vein to [this question which modifies a TikZ plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485101/put-exam-answerline-blanks-as-nodes-inside-tikzpicture), I would like LaTeX to decide to print ONE of the following :

- an empty axis for drawing a graph when `\printanswers` is commented out
- The solution plot on top of the axis when `\printanswers` is uncommented.

Below is my MWE, which currently prints two separate plots:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[margin=.75 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={grid,
axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}}
}

%The following is to make a node style answer which has by default text opacity=0 but changes to text opacity=1 when \printanswers is issued. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485101/put-exam-answerline-blanks-as-nodes-inside-tikzpicture
\tikzset{answer/.style={draw,text opacity=0}}
\let\oldprintanswers\printanswers
\def\printanswers{\oldprintanswers\tikzset{answer/.style={text opacity=1}}}
\printanswers

\begin{document}
\section{Exam}
\begin{questions}
\question[20] (Graphing)
Graph $y=\frac{1}{2}x-3$:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my style, height=7cm,
xtick={-5,-4,...,5}, ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-6, ymax=6]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{solution}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my style, height=7cm,
xtick={-5,-4,...,5}, ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-6, ymax=6]
\addplot[domain=-6:6, samples=100, mark=none, thick, blue]{1/2*x-3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{solution}

\newpage

\question[20] Fill in the designated angles and coordinates in the following unit circle.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]
% draw the coordinates
\draw[->] (-1.5cm,0cm) -- (1.5cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0cm,-1.5cm) -- (0cm,1.5cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};
% draw the unit circle
\draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);
\foreach \x in {0,30,...,360} {
        % lines from center to point
        \draw[gray] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:1cm);
        % dots at each point
        \filldraw[black] (\x:1cm) circle(0.4pt);
        % draw each angle in degrees
        \draw (\x:0.6cm) node[fill=white] {$\x^\circ$};
}
\foreach \x in {0,45,...,360} {
        % lines from center to point
        \draw[gray] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:1cm);
        % dots at each point
        \filldraw[black] (\x:1cm) circle(0.4pt);
        % draw each angle in degrees
        \draw (\x:0.6cm) node[fill=white] {$\x^\circ$};
}
% draw each angle in radians
\foreach \x/\xtext in {
    30/\frac{\pi}{6},
    45/\frac{\pi}{4},
    60/\frac{\pi}{3},
    90/\frac{\pi}{2},
    120/\frac{2\pi}{3},
    135/\frac{3\pi}{4},
    150/\frac{5\pi}{6},
    180/\pi,
    210/\frac{7\pi}{6},
    225/\frac{5\pi}{4},
    240/\frac{4\pi}{3},
    270/\frac{3\pi}{2},
    300/\frac{5\pi}{3},
    315/\frac{7\pi}{4},
    330/\frac{11\pi}{6},
    360/2\pi}
        \draw (\x:0.85cm) node[fill=white,answer] {$\xtext$};
\foreach \x/\xtext/\y in {
    % the coordinates for the first quadrant
    30/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/\frac{1}{2},
    45/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
    60/\frac{1}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
    % the coordinates for the second quadrant
    150/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/\frac{1}{2},
    135/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
    120/-\frac{1}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
    % the coordinates for the third quadrant
    210/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
    225/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
    240/-\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
    % the coordinates for the fourth quadrant
    330/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
    315/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
    300/\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}
        \draw (\x:1.25cm) node[fill=white,answer] {$\left(\xtext,\y\right)$};
% draw the horizontal and vertical coordinates
\draw (-1.25cm,0cm) node[fill=white,answer] {$(-1,0)$}
      (1.25cm,0cm)  node[fill=white,answer] {$(1,0)$}
      (0cm,-1.25cm) node[fill=white,answer] {$(0,-1)$}
      (0cm,1.25cm)  node[fill=white,answer] {$(0,1)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone think of an elegant way to accomplish this? Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works like the linked answer: the opacity is `0` initially if you add `answer plot` to the options of `\addplot`,

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[margin=.75 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={grid,
axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}}
}

%The following is to make a node style answer which has by default text opacity=0 but changes to text opacity=1 when \printanswers is issued. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485101/put-exam-answerline-blanks-as-nodes-inside-tikzpicture
\tikzset{answer/.style={draw,text opacity=0},answer plot/.style={opacity=0}}
\let\oldprintanswers\printanswers
\def\printanswers{\oldprintanswers\tikzset{answer/.style={text opacity=1},
answer plot/.style={opacity=1}}}
%\printanswers

\begin{document}
\section{Exam}
\begin{questions}
\question[20] (Graphing)
Graph $y=\frac{1}{2}x-3$:

%\begin{solution}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my style, height=7cm,
xtick={-5,-4,...,5}, ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-6, ymax=6]
\addplot[domain=-6:6, samples=100, mark=none, thick, blue,answer plot]{1/2*x-3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%\end{solution}

\newpage

\question[20] Fill in the designated angles and coordinates in the following unit circle.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]
% draw the coordinates
\draw[->] (-1.5cm,0cm) -- (1.5cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0cm,-1.5cm) -- (0cm,1.5cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};
% draw the unit circle
\draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);
\foreach \x in {0,30,...,360} {
        % lines from center to point
        \draw[gray] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:1cm);
        % dots at each point
        \filldraw[black] (\x:1cm) circle(0.4pt);
        % draw each angle in degrees
        \draw (\x:0.6cm) node[fill=white] {$\x^\circ$};
}
\foreach \x in {0,45,...,360} {
        % lines from center to point
        \draw[gray] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:1cm);
        % dots at each point
        \filldraw[black] (\x:1cm) circle(0.4pt);
        % draw each angle in degrees
        \draw (\x:0.6cm) node[fill=white] {$\x^\circ$};
}
% draw each angle in radians
\foreach \x/\xtext in {
    30/\frac{\pi}{6},
    45/\frac{\pi}{4},
    60/\frac{\pi}{3},
    90/\frac{\pi}{2},
    120/\frac{2\pi}{3},
    135/\frac{3\pi}{4},
    150/\frac{5\pi}{6},
    180/\pi,
    210/\frac{7\pi}{6},
    225/\frac{5\pi}{4},
    240/\frac{4\pi}{3},
    270/\frac{3\pi}{2},
    300/\frac{5\pi}{3},
    315/\frac{7\pi}{4},
    330/\frac{11\pi}{6},
    360/2\pi}
        \draw (\x:0.85cm) node[fill=white,answer] {$\xtext$};
\foreach \x/\xtext/\y in {
    % the coordinates for the first quadrant
    30/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/\frac{1}{2},
    45/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
    60/\frac{1}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
    % the coordinates for the second quadrant
    150/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/\frac{1}{2},
    135/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
    120/-\frac{1}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
    % the coordinates for the third quadrant
    210/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
    225/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
    240/-\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
    % the coordinates for the fourth quadrant
    330/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
    315/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
    300/\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}
        \draw (\x:1.25cm) node[fill=white,answer] {$\left(\xtext,\y\right)$};
% draw the horizontal and vertical coordinates
\draw (-1.25cm,0cm) node[fill=white,answer] {$(-1,0)$}
      (1.25cm,0cm)  node[fill=white,answer] {$(1,0)$}
      (0cm,-1.25cm) node[fill=white,answer] {$(0,-1)$}
      (0cm,1.25cm)  node[fill=white,answer] {$(0,1)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but gets set to `1` if `\printanswers` is uncommented, i.e. you remove the `%` before  `\printanswers`.

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [optional](https://ctan.org/pkg/optional) package, with lines like

```
\usepackage[answers]{optional} % or use "noanswers"
```

and then instead of commenting or uncommenting `\printanswers`, you would pass "answers" or "noanswers" to the `optional` package. Then use commands like

```
\opt{answers}{\printanswers}
...
\opt{noanswers}{\begin{tikzpicture} ... just axes here ...}
```